# Improve the algorithm of how the code works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a line both on the site https://www.sibirix.ru/. So that when you hover it becomes a wave.
It turned out quite well. But unfortunately not as on the site. Help please, tell me what is not right.
My [code](https://jsfiddle.net/alexey10mentor/sbruj9d2/1/)....
Download the code from the site, it does not work. There's a lot of everything.
I will be very grateful to everyone who will help me in this task.

```js
$('.js-line-wave').on('mouseenter, mousemove', function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        $('.line, .button_wave, .line_item').each(function(index, letter) {        
            var posx = index; 
            var dx = relativeX-posx*4.7;
            var posy = -Math.cos(dx/50)*50*(5/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.E,-Math.pow(dx/150,2))

             $(letter).css("transform", "translateY(" + posy + "px)");
        });


});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

section.tp_section {
  padding-top: 144px;
  padding-bottom: 88px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
}

.line_wave_block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 95px 0 53px;
}

.line_wave_block .line {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line_wave_block .line:before {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 174, 239, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button_wave,
.line_item {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.button_wave {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.line_wave_block .button_wave::before {
  content: '';
  width: 33px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00EBDB, #008FF2);
}

.line_wave_block .button_wave:hover::before,
.line_wave_block .button_wave.active::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF8070, #FF5971);
}

.tons_text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -54px;
  color: #5F42DF;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.line_wave_block .line_item::before {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 174, 239, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <section class="tp_section tp_block js-tp">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="line_wave_block js-line-wave">
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave active" href="#tab1">
          <div class="tons_text">
            1,5
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab2">
          <div class="tons_text">
            3
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab3">
          <div class="tons_text">
            5
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab4">
          <div class="tons_text">
            10
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab5">
          <div class="tons_text">
            20
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>




</div>
```

Comment: What is expected output? Could you please add it as image to question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11SrFBqTVGq4TZA_nDOEDz91pYMsWfZJE/view .I need both on the site. Your option is not quite right (

Comment: Edited..........

Comment: All the same not that that is necessary. On the site the line is not the whole wave. Look at the example please. https://www.sibirix.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Change is here:

```
$('.line, .button_wave, .line_item').each(function(index, letter) {
     var posx = letter.offsetLeft;
     var dx = relativeX-posx;
     var posy = -Math.cos(dx/50)*50;

     $(letter).css("transform", "translateY(" + posy + "px)");
});
```

```js
$('.js-line-wave').on('mouseenter, mousemove', function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        $('.line, .button_wave, .line_item').each(function(index, letter) {
            var posx = letter.offsetLeft;
            var dx = relativeX-posx;
            var posy = -Math.cos(dx/50)*50;

             $(letter).css("transform", "translateY(" + posy + "px)");
        });


});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

section.tp_section {
  padding-top: 144px;
  padding-bottom: 88px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
}

.line_wave_block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 95px 0 53px;
}

.line_wave_block .line {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line_wave_block .line:before {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 174, 239, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button_wave,
.line_item {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.button_wave {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.line_wave_block .button_wave::before {
  content: '';
  width: 33px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00EBDB, #008FF2);
}

.line_wave_block .button_wave:hover::before,
.line_wave_block .button_wave.active::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF8070, #FF5971);
}

.tons_text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -54px;
  color: #5F42DF;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.line_wave_block .line_item::before {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 174, 239, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <section class="tp_section tp_block js-tp">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="line_wave_block js-line-wave">
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave active" href="#tab1">
          <div class="tons_text">
            1,5
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab2">
          <div class="tons_text">
            3
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab3">
          <div class="tons_text">
            5
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab4">
          <div class="tons_text">
            10
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="line_item"></div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <a class="button_wave" href="#tab5">
          <div class="tons_text">
            20
          </div>
        </a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>




</div>
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11SrFBqTVGq4TZA_nDOEDz91pYMsWfZJE/view .I need both on the site. Your option is not quite right (